# functions.php code is printed on screen wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to make a child theme and everything looked ok untill I changed php version from 5.6 to 7.2.1, what is happening is that functions.php code is printed (echoed) on the screen, check the image out, if I'm not making sense.

[This is the very top of my home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnwSS.png)

This is my functions.php, which is only an example from wordpress to show you whats happening:

```
<?function wporg_shortcode($atts = [], $content = null, $tag = '')
{
    // normalize attribute keys, lowercase
    $atts = array_change_key_case((array)$atts, CASE_LOWER);

    // override default attributes with user attributes
    $wporg_atts = shortcode_atts([
         "title" => "WordPress.org",
     ], $atts, $tag);

    // start output
    $o = '';

    // start box
    $o .= '<div class="wporg-box">';

    // title
    $o .= '<h2>' . esc_html__($wporg_atts['title'], 'wporg') . '</h2>';

    // enclosing tags
    if (!is_null($content)) {
        // secure output by executing the_content filter hook on $content
        $o .= apply_filters('the_content', $content);

        // run shortcode parser recursively
        $o .= do_shortcode($content);
    }

    // end box
    $o .= '</div>';

    // return output
    return $o;
}

function wporg_shortcodes_init()
{
    add_shortcode('wporg', 'wporg_shortcode');
}

add_action('init', 'wporg_shortcodes_init');
```

Comment: Replace the opening `<?` with `<?php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start file from `<?php` not from `<?`

Comment: Enabling short tags is bad practice, its off for a reason. #1 would suffice.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone agreed. I've just googled it and found good description why it is so: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php
Edited my answer

Comment: Thank you so much guys, you save my ass!

Answer (score 1):

> Some times **Wordpress** doesn't detect short tags `<? ?>` in Php due
>   to changing the version from 5.6 to 7.0. So you need to start `<?php
>   enclosing with the ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Simply apply basic php tag at start and end.